# My android application crashes the moment i touch a button

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android programming, and sometimes i have no idea what the wrong with my project, it crushes the moment i touch a button.
is there anything wrong?

Here's my Main Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id==R.id.menu_home)


    if (id==R.id.menu_search)


    if (id==R.id.menu_contact)


    if (id==R.id.menu_info)


    if (id==R.id.menu_close)

    finish();

return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



public void btn_next1 (View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Page1.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void btn_next2 (View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Page2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void btn_next3 (View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Page3.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void btn_next4 (View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Page4.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void btn_next5 (View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Page5.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void btn_next6 (View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Page6.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void btn_next10 (View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Page10.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

and Here's my activity_main.xml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="89dp"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:background="@drawable/page10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:onClick="btn_next10"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.028"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.909" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_width="89dp"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:background="@drawable/page6"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:onClick="btn_next6"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.971"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.456" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_width="89dp"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:background="@drawable/page5"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:onClick="btn_next5"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.456" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="89dp"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:background="@drawable/page4"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:onClick="btn_next4"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.028"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.456" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="89dp"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:background="@drawable/page3"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:onClick="btn_next3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.971"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.129" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="89dp"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:background="@drawable/page2"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:onClick="btn_next2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.129" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="89dp"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:background="@drawable/page1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:onClick="btn_next1"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.028"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.129" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Can you help me guys?

Comment: Can you add the logcat

Comment: `Can you help me guys?` Not without seeing the error logs.

Answer (score 0):

You have added the onClick to buttons which look fine.
Check if you have declared Page1.class and other classes in your Manifest file. If not, then you need to add them just like your MainActivity is defined in your Manifest file. 
Also, check your logcat for the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Check **Android Monitor** when your app has stopped unfortunately.

Don't forget to declare classes in Manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Do the activities Page1, Page 2 etc exist? If so, maybe it's one of these that is failing. As above, your logcat would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Throw try catch exception in your onCreateOptionMenu

Sometimes nullpointer exception arises wheh return type is boolean like true... which leads in crashing your App.

Hope it helps!